# How to develop GWT widget?

Tags: java, gwt, gantt-chart

I want to develop my GWT Widget. This widget draws Gantt chart and has drag - drop property. It will be simple form of [Deskera](http://www.deskera.com/)

Where can I start to develop this widget? Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tutorial covers how to create a GWT module:

http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=229

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [gChart](http://code.google.com/p/gchart/) and maybe look at the source too.  Good example of a custom widget.

Comment: +1 just because I didn't know about this widget, and now I want to use it on my web page.

Comment: yea, I've used it a few times.  Really easy to add in the component.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the Gxt Gantt, built on the Ext GWT framework.
[Gxt Gantt 2.0](http://www.gxt-scheduler.com/gxtgantt.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can develop the chart purely in java using google web toolkit. Or if you have any exsting javascript for your chart you can use this with the HTML control from GWT.